# i have a access database i want to generate ID for column userId but when i deleted i record i want my code to use it's id again

Tags: c#

i have a access database i want to generate ID for column userId but when i deleted i record i want my code to use it's id again
this is my code

```
                public int codeUsers()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select userId from Users",connection);
        da.Fill(dt);
        var value = dt.Rows[0][0];
        if (value==DBNull.Value)
        {
            myNewIdUsers = 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    myNewIdUsers = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][0]) + 1;
                    break;
                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][0]) != Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i+1][0]) - 1)
                {
                    myNewIdUsers = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][0]) + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


            return myNewIdUsers;
    }
```

i don't know why it didn't work

Comment: Why would you want to do that? are you afraid you'll run out of numbers?

Comment: If userID is an Autonumber field then do not try to make it work as you like. It is a waste of time.

Comment: no it's not Auto number filed

Answer (score 0):

looks like you were missing a parentheses for the `for` statement in your code, I added it...could that be your problem??

Comment: where you didn't change any thing

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem just ordering my data in the sql statement the code is

```
 public int codeUsers()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select userId from Users order by userId",connection);
        da.Fill(dt);
        var value = dt.Rows[0][0];
        if (value==DBNull.Value)
        {
            myNewIdUsers = 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    myNewIdUsers = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][0]) + 1;
                    break;
                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][0]) != Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i+1][0]) - 1)
                {
                    myNewIdUsers = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][0]) + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


            return myNewIdUsers;
    }
```